# Python linear interpolation of a matrix from csv file

Tags: python, csv, matrix, interpolation

I am very new to python, which I have been working with since starting my undergrads last year.

Background:
I have a csv file with a x, y, z matrix where x is distance, y is height and z is a parameter.
 Basically a variation of a parameter over height and distance, where x (distance) increases in the columns downwards, and y (height) in the rows towards the right.

Problem:
The interval in x and y defining the variation in height and distance and thus related z.

Objective:
Lnearly interpolate x and y, and thus z too, to a different interval.

Example of current intervals:
x: min = 0, max = 99.22, *interval = 0.041*
y: min = 0, max = 83.72, *interval = 0.104*

Desired results:
x: min = 0, max = 99, *interval = 0.02*
y: min = 0, max = 84, *interval = 0.10*

Can anyone kindly help with this? I am sure it is a very simple problem but I am still an unwise Padawan.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

python already have a library called **numpy** that can help you work with linear algebra and have a lot of good stuffs.

You can start to learn here:
https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html

To read the csv file you can use another famous library called **pandas**.

You can see about in that link: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

As an example your code to read the csv will be like that:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('your_file')

x = df['x'].tonumpy()
y = df['y'].tonumpy()
z = df['z'].tonumpy()
```

That you your x, y and z will be treated as numpy arrays.

You can use the **numpy** function **linspace** to create an array with spaced values, like that:

```
foo = np.linspace(0, 99, 0.02)
```

The numpy automatically build the array **foo** with the values from 0 to 99 with 0.02 space.

Comment: Thanks much, that was great!